# Подскажите как добавить изображение в пост тг бота

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

Я написал код, чтобы посты в тг боте публиковались автоматически после нажатия пользователем кнопки /start. Мне нужно к этим постам добавить изображение, а не просто текст. Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу это сделать?

Вот сам код

```
import time
import logging
import asyncio

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

TOKEN = ""
MSG = "Программировал ли ты сегодня, {}?"

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot=bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_handler(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    user_name = message.from_user.first_name
    user_full_name = message.from_user.full_name
    logging.info(f'{user_id} {user_full_name} {time.asctime()}')
    await message.reply(f"Привет, {user_full_name}! Это первый урок в этом обучении")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay=10)
    await message.reply(f"Это второй урок в этом обучении")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay=10)
    await message.reply(f"Это третий урок в этом обучении")
    await asyncio.sleep(delay=10)
    await message.reply(f"Это четвертый урок в этом обучении")




    for i in range(7):
        await asyncio.sleep(60*60*24)
        await bot.send_message(user_id, MSG.format(user_name))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Исправил, надеюсь я понятно объяснил:)

Answer (score 0):

эта функция должна вам помочь, если картинки у вас расположены локально.

```
async def send_picture(chat_id, file_path):
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat_id, photo=InputFile(f))
```